# compare strings with strcmp function works different

Tags: c++, strcmp, string.h

I'm comparing two strings with strcmp in the following manner:

```
long t=1011;
char tc[10], tcr[10];
ltoa(t,tc,10);
cout<<tc<<endl;  //prints 1011
strcpy(tcr, strrev(tc));
cout<<tcr<<endl; //prints 1101
cout<<strcmp(tc,tcr);
```

This gives me a result of 0, which indicates that the strings are equal. However, when I try:

```
cout<<strcmp("1011", "1101"); // prints -1 thats okay
```

I get the expected value of -1. What's am I doing wrong? I am using devc++ compiler version 4.9.9.2

Comment: strrev function changes tc string (it works on tc array). After strrev and strcpy tcr is equal to tc.

Comment: Yes Adam you are right it works in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how function `strrev` is defined, If it reverses the argument in place then the result is expected because tc was reversed.

For example function `strrev` can be declared the following way

```
char * strrev( char *s );
```

and the return value and the value of the argument will be equal.

Take into account that `strrev` is not a standard function.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code like so:

```
long t=1011;
char tc[10], tcr[10];
ltoa(t,tc,10);
strcpy(tcr, strrev(tc));
cout<<tc<<endl; 
cout<<tcr<<endl;
cout<<strcmp(tc,tcr);
```

then you'll see that tc and tcr are the same. strrev reverses the input string in place, and 1101 is printed twice.